# i want to show update tkinter canvas realtime

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, tkinter-canvas

I try your is not update text after text update 1

```
def main_ai():
    master = Tk()
    master.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')
    master.title("Reverse vending")
    canvas = Canvas(master, width=1280, height=1024)
    canvas.pack()
```

Show text program

```
def check(canvas,master):
  w_b=0
  text_id=canvas.create_text(740, 470, text=0,font=("Sukhumvit set",70),fill="white")
  text_ig=canvas.create_text(740, 690, text=0.0,font=("Sukhumvit set",70),fill="white")
  #master.after(1000,lambda:master.destroy())
  #master.mainloop()
  while True:
      if check_fullbottle()==500: #check total number of bottles 
          break
      master.after(1000,check_distance())
      w_b+=1

    master.after(2000,lambda:changetext(text_id,text_ig,w_b,canvas,master))
    #master.after(3000,lambda:master.destroy())
    master.after(1000,check_button(w_b,master))
    end_loop(w_b,master)
 master.mainloop()
 return w_b
```

## Change text is terrible

```
def change_text(text_id,text_ig,w_b,canvas,master):
  canvas.itemconfig(text_id,text=w_b).update()
  canvas.itemconfig(text_ig,text=w_b*0.1).update()
```

It show 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'update'.

## Text show is terrible

```
def check(canvas,master):
 w_b=0
 text_id=canvas.create_text(740, 470, text="asdsad",font=("Sukhumvit set",70),fill="white").pack()
 text_ig=canvas.create_text(740, 690, text="sdf",font=("Sukhumvit set",70),fill="white").pack()
```

It show 'int' object has no attribute 'pack'

Thank you for Help me

Comment: What is the changetext function? You can remove all the contents of the canvas and redraw what you need, and call `master.update()`

Comment: I have new problem ,It show gray display help me!!

Comment: Did you redraw on the canvas?